# How to extract .apk file and put it into Eclipse for running?

Tags: android

I am quite new in Android and I intended to run some sample programming downloaded from the web, but I faced problem in extracting the .apk file, in the .apk file there are META-INF, res, manifest, .dex and .arsc, how I am going to open the sample program in the Eclipse? I just wanna run some sample coding... Thanks.

Comment: If you want to debug, review, modify the program, you'll need the source from which the .apk was built.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to open the program in eclipse to run it.

Just type

```
adb install -r filename.apk
```

The -r flag is to allow re-install if it already exists with the same signature.  If it exists with an incompatible signature you will have to remove it.

If adb complains you have multiple devices, do

```
adb devices
```

Notice the serial number of the one you want, and then

```
adb -s SERIAL -r filename.apk
```

Actually opening an existing apk in eclipse would be relatively pointless without a depackager/decompiler, which is another topic altogether.